# Improve generation of data over a year

Tags: r

I need to estimate the mpg of a number of cars for each day of the year. Depending on the type of carbs with random selection. The following code works fine, but I would like to optimize because the data will be larger. I would like to reduce the processing time which lasts about 20 seconds on my server. Is there a way to improve this code?

Data:

```
tib_mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars)
```

Optimized function to randomly retrieve a list of cars mpg based on some predefined fuel type:

```
 get_sample_mpg_list <- function (list_carbs){
      as.data.frame(tib_mtcars) %>%
        select(carb, mpg) %>%
        nest_by(carb) %>%
        filter(carb %in% list_carbs) %>%
        mutate(data = map2(data, table(list_carbs)[as.character(carb)],
                           ~sample(.x,.y)))%>%
        unnest(data)
    }
```

Prepare loop information, and data frame for the result :

```
date_start <- '2020-01-01'
date_end <- '2020-12-31'

days <- seq(from=as.Date(date_start), to=as.Date(date_end), by='days' )

df_result = data.frame()
```

Here the loop that will be wrapped in a function (with the dates in parameters) :

Two variables date and id will be added in the data frame

```
t1 <- Sys.time()

for ( i in seq_along(days) )
{
  list_carbs <- sample (c(1:8))

  output <- get_sample_mpg_list(list_carbs)

  output$date <- paste0(days[i], "T12:00:00")

  df = rbind(df, output)
}

df_result <- mutate(df_result, id=row_number())

t2 <- Sys.time()
print(difftime(t2, t1, units = "secs"))
```

Comment: also, if you can describe a little bit more what `list_carbs` might actually look like ( for example will it be a single value, like in your example loop, or a vector of unique values, or a vector of possibly duplicate values), i can further optimize the solution below to fit your situation

Comment: "list_carbs"  can be a vector with duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

`list_carbs` can be a vector of duplicate values.

One way to do this is to create a revised verison of your sampling function that leverages a `data.table` join, and the special `.BY`.

```
library(data.table)
dt_mtcars = data.table(mtcars)

f <- function(carb) {
  data.table(table(carb))[,carb:=as.numeric(carb)][dt_mtcars, on=.(carb), nomatch=0][
    ,.(data = as.double(sample(mpg,.BY$N, replace=T))), by=.(carb,N)
  ]
}
```

Now, we make a source data table that has the vector of carb values for each of the days of interest.  In my example here, I've generated a random sample of 25 values of `carb` with duplicates, using `sample(1:8, 25, replace=T)`, and then simply apply the function `f()` to each vector of carbs

```
set.seed(123)
source = data.table(date=days)[, .(carb=sample(1:8, 25, replace=T)), by=date]
source[, f(carb), by=date]
```

Output:

```
            date carb N data
   1: 2020-01-01    4 2 21.0
   2: 2020-01-01    4 2 21.0
   3: 2020-01-01    1 4 33.9
   4: 2020-01-01    1 4 18.1
   5: 2020-01-01    1 4 22.8
  ---                       
6835: 2020-12-31    6 3 12.0
6836: 2020-12-31    8 4  1.0
6837: 2020-12-31    8 4 13.0
6838: 2020-12-31    8 4  5.0
6839: 2020-12-31    8 4  7.0
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the data table package. After some learning I finally managed to integrate your solution (really helpful) into my program